# Broken pipe error of Java NIO under concurrent test

Tags: java, concurrency, webserver, nio, java-io

I am now building an event-driven server, using Java NIO

When I did `ab -n 100 -c 100 localhost:8080/`, everything is fine.
But when I did `ab -n 10000 -c 1000 localhost:8080/`, error occurred!!

The part of the code:

```
resHeader.append("Host: MyServer" + CRLF);
resHeader.append("Connection: close" + CRLF + CRLF);
ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.wrap(resHeader.toString().getBytes());--(ClientHandler.java:372)
while(temp.hasRemaining()) {
    client.write(temp);
}
```

The definition of client: `client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();`

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
    at ClientHandler.sendResponse(ClientHandler.java:372)
    at ClientHandler.parseRequest(ClientHandler.java:218)
    at ClientHandler.writeKey(ClientHandler.java:136)
    at ClientHandler.execute(ClientHandler.java:51)
    at TcpServer.main(TcpServer.java:33)
```

After the error, I add this to the code:

```
ByteBuffer temp = null;
try {
    temp = ByteBuffer.wrap(resHeader.toString().getBytes());
    while(temp.hasRemaining()) {
        client.write(temp);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("TEST: " + temp.hasRemaining());
    System.out.println("connect:" + client.isConnected()
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And when the errors pop up again, it prints `"TEST: true"` and `"connect:true"` which means that it does not finish writing. Why this happened?

Also, I used `ab -c 1000 -n 10000 -r http://localhost:8080/`

```
-r : Don't exit on socket receive errors.

    Concurrency Level:      1000
    Time taken for tests:   18.700 seconds
    Complete requests:      10000
    Failed requests:        1878

   (Connect: 0, Receive: 626, Length: 626, Exceptions: 626)
```

(PS: Using this `-r` I did not get the errors: `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe`)

Does this provide some useful information?

Comment: What's the maximum number of open sockets you can have per process for your OS? Also, could ab have prematurely closed a socket?

Answer (score 0):

'Broken pipe' means that the peer closed the connection prematurely. It could do that under load for any number of reasons, none of which have anything to do with your code.